# Converting HTML Code in TextBox to display Correctly (after input through a keyboard made in XAML)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've created a Keyboard for my WPF application in XAML with the functionality of it done in the code behind C#. As of now, any key clicked (or touched), will display the respective key in a TextBox (as expected. However, when handling the HTML Code, the HTML Code gets displayed.

For reference, the button click:

```
private void btnQUOTATION_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        HandleKeyboard("&quot;");
    }
```

The `HandleKeyboard` method:

```
     private bool current spot = false;
        private void HandleKeyboard(string key)
        {

            //Ternary operator
            string valueSoFar = currentSpot ? txtBoxTest.Text : "";
            string newValue = valueSoFar + key.ToString();
            txtBoxTest.Text = newValue;
            currentSpot = true;
        }
```

Everything is fine and dandy with the other keys presented, except for quotation marks and apostrophes.

What I'm expecting in the TextBox `txtBoxTest` when the button for quotation marks is clicked (`&quot;`) is quote marks to show in the text box as quotation marks...instead of the HTML code it is showing now.

Since `HandleKeyboard()` cannot accept `(""")` or `("'")` ... Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look to use the [Encode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmlencode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [Decode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmldecode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) HTML. You will need to use `System.Web` namespace.

e.g.

```
string key= "This is a &quot;";
string deCodedKey = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(key);
```

If you put a breakpoint over the DeCodedKey line you should see it change back to ""

Comment: Then I can pass `deCodedKey` to my `HandleKeyboard` method to be displayed! Perfect! Worked exactly as hoped. Marked as answer! :)